# Print Duplicate Values Of an Excel Sheet based on a key sidewise or downwise using Python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, merge

I have few duplicate values for a provided key in my excel sheet and i want to either highlight them, or print all the values including the duplicate values sideways or downways using Python.

I have been successful to print the duplicate code downwards with the provided code but it works for more than two sheets.

For two sheets it gives the result as provided in the picture below where only the duplicates are printed and not other information. 
The Key for my table is `'Customer No'`

Table 1:

```
Customer No    Sales Quantity     Invoice Point
2010            1004              JJ
2011            1005              KK
2012            1010              LL
2013            1009              MM
2014            1008              NN
```

Table 2:

```
Sales Quantity    P.Description    P.Location    P.Type    Customer No
1001              Lakhotia Plant   AAAA          TO        2012
1002              Shyam Steel      ZZZZ          TO        2013
1003              bad              WWWW          TA        2020
1004              okay             UUUU          TI        2021
1005              good             PPPP          TY        2022
```

Result Table:

```
Customer No  Sales Quantity  Invoice Point  P.Description  P.Location P.Type
2010            1004              JJ
2011            1005              KK
2012            1010              LL
2012            1001                        Lakhotia Plant   AAAA     TO  
2013            1009              MM
2013            1002                        Shyam Steel      ZZZZ     TO
2014            1008              NN
2020            1003                        bad              WWWW     TA
2021            1004                        okay             UUUU     TI                           
2022            1005                        good             PPPP     TY
```

Here details of 2012 and 2013 have been given downways along with other records

My code:

```py
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import glob

    df=pd.read_excel("C:/Users/Downloads/sales-mar-2014.xlsx")
    status=pd.read_excel("C:/Users/Downloads/customer-status.xlsx")

    all_data_st=pd.merge(df,status,on='Customer No')


    all_data_st.to_excel("E:/final.xlsx",header=True, index=False)
```

And the output is coming as:

[image: Result]

The link to the sheets where Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 are my dataframes and sheet 3 is my expected result:

[Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YJmOGrqcQ0JVxBFOYqDNlOUa8_7UG2mP-519CpvxF34/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: can you provide the 2 dataframes as a sample(5 rows) and expected output(all as text) in the question? We cant copy images, neither do we know how the data looks like.

Comment: hey @anky_91, i have attached a link to a google sheet where the first and the second sheets are the dataframes and the third sheet being my expected result.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot access google sheets. Office work space limitations. lets hope someone can

Comment: No problem, Thanks!

Comment: Should i type here the tables as text @anky_91 ?

Comment: yes, ,ideally for every pandas questions, you should have data to represent your question. And Expected output so people can relate and come up with a solution. :)

Comment: @anky_91 i have given my datas over here, kindly go through it...

Comment: try with `final=(df1.merge(df2,how='outer',on=['Customer No','Sales Quantity'])
 .sort_values('Customer No').fillna(''))` and then print(final), if you dont want spaces, remove the `.fillna('')` from the code. `df1` and `df2` are `Table 1` and `Table 2` respectively

Comment: @anky_91 its giving an appended output and duplicates cannot be detecyted there

Comment: "Resultant Table" in the question was the expected output? or did I get it wrong. can you explain what you want to do and paste the output in the question for me. Thanks